# I can not start the project in windows 10 for iis 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I can not start the project. 
Earlier, on windows 7 everything worked.

But when I switched to 10, the project stopped running, giving me a HTTP 500 error.

I can not fix who knows what the problem is?

I checked all the references in the assembly, it seems, everything is in order.
In DEBUG find error -

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiW5m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  re-install Nuget Package.